# What are ASUS EEE 1225B partitions for and how to install ubuntu there

Tags: ubuntu, lubuntu, eee-pc

I just bought ASUS EEE 1225B with no pre-installed OS and I want to install Lubuntu there. Yet there are some partitions already:

```
sda1  reiserf  10GB
sda2  fat32    17GB
sda3  ntfs    470GB
sda4           18MB
```

I would try to install it by repartitioning the sda3 but there are some 3GB of data and I don't know what to do with it?

What are they for and what to do with them to install Lubuntu but not to make some damage to the functionality of the netbook?

Comment: If you're curious to boot from any of those partitions, then get a copy of the `gparted` live CD.  There's a menu to boot from the 1st, 2nd, 3rd or 4th partition of a HDD.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a fresh laptop it is safe to remove all the partitions and install your own layout.

It looks like there was something on the disk before you bought it, maybe some kind of system to test the hardware. If this is the case I'd assume that `/dev/sda4` was the partition with the `/boot` folder as it is the only unformated one and maybe was deleted before selling it.

Comment: Well, it has certainly at least that ASUS Express Gate Cloud thing. A kind of mini-OS with some applications. I don't need it really, but I would let it be. I hoped I can identify it on the partitions and go on installing lubuntu, but it seems complex. Is this ASUS Express Gate Clou on the FAT partition? And what with the stuff on the NTFS partition?

Comment: It would be best to examine the contents of the folders. If in doubt make a backup of the disk to an external medium, afterwards you can try to delete stuff. There probably are better ways for making full disk backups, but I'd be lazy and just use `dd`.

Comment: Well, backing up is not that easy on a netbook with my only pendrive used as a Lubuntu LiveCD ;) I managed however to mount the partitions and it turned out the NTFS one is indeed only Recycler and System Volume Information, the FAT32 one is the ASUS EGC and reiserfs is (judging by names) some form of backup for the EGC. So I'll remove the NTFS partition and see does the ASUS thing annoy me during the daily usage... Thanks everybody for help.